# Accessing a view controller created in the app delegate from another controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am loading my GPS controller, which is finding the user's current location, from my app delegate, but my problem is accessing the GPS view from another view controller. How can I do that?

Comment: @MattBall I have made a class which is retrieving users current location and it works nice. But now i want to load this class from my app delegate because when application will start then this gps class will get the users location and it will show every step of the full application.is it clear to you now???

Comment: You have asked in the first part of the question that you want to load GPS controller from your appdelegate.But in the second half of the question you have mentioned that you already loaded the GPS controller from app delegate.Exactly what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to look into `corelocation` API 
[Core Location Tuorial](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/)

1) The location updates are received asynchronously and hence you need to respond to them immediately according to the time-stamp for

2) Always check the timestamp and compare it with current timestamp so that you can check if it is latest.

3) Stop the service once you received updates as wifi GPS etc drains battery real fast.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear of what you want to achieve though. anyway you can use `CLLocationManager` from the `CoreLocation` framework to get the GPS location

Declare this in your `appdelegate.h`

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

And in the appdelegate.m use this

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

You also need to implement the following delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

For more detalied explanation see [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application) for the tutorial